# Which is the best method for storing data for a Language Dictionary?

Tags: database, search-engine, indexing

I have been working on making a completely offline dictionary using the Wiktionary XML dumps. The dumps themselves are about 10 MB, but when converted into a index using a search engine indexer (I use Whoosh Search Engine in Python), the complete index comes to about 250 MB. Which I think would be difficult to distribute, it might be zipped, still it won't come anywhere near 10 MB. And indexing takes about 1 hour in my system, so indexing while installing the software in a PC is tedious.

So I am looking for an alternate way of storing the words and meanings to make the dictionary. Which is a better searchable solution? May be some sort of Data Base that produces light weight DBs.

Or the search engine indexes are better than DBs?

Comment: +1: I don't know if this is on topic here, but if people have information about what works well for (large) dictionary databases, I'm possibly interested.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Directed Acyclic Word Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_deterministic_finite_automaton) data structure, which is designed to be a highly space-economical way to store dictionaries.  They are commonly used on mobile phones, where economizing storage space is important.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a data structure that's obvious when you think about it but cool nonetheless. Just looking at the name I thought "Sounds like a trie except…ah, clever".

Comment: Any examples of Python libraries or implementations?